# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object (PHP xPath) however there is an object?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, wamp

I am running a **PHP** script (using **xPath**) to extract values from an **HTML** file. It works fine however some records are failing.

When inspecting the HTML file, the fields do contain values. For other fields, the values are returned when the text is the same? I am unsure why I am getting a "non object" error message?

The fields in question contain a combination of text and numeric values (eg 100pd and £100 plus).

How can I clean the node value so it returns a value?

**[UPDATE:]**
I believe that the for loop is causing the error as loop based on $string0 and not $string 2.

Code:

```
$string0 = $xpath->query("//div[@class='jobListSkillsPanel']/span[@id='summreference']", $element);
 ..    
$string2 = $xpath->query("//div[@class='jobListDetailsPanel']/span[@id='rate']", $element);

..
for ($i = 0; $i < $string0->length; $i++) {
..
..
$str = $string2->item($i)->nodeValue; // Line 38: Creates Error
echo $str . '|' ;
```

Error:

```
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 
 C:\wamp\www\PHP_SCRAPER\_jobs\xpath5.php on line 38
```

Comment: where is the line 38?

Comment: Line 38: `$str = $string2->item($i)->nodeValue;` // Added more code above. I believe that my loop is broken.

Comment: So $string2 returns FALSE! Fix your query.